# Awk add the numbers in three colums and return only one column

Tags: bash, awk

I need to add three columns, the ones that start with an **x**, and return only one column with sum of the three numbers. the other rows must remain intact

I know how to add columns but I can't figure out how to do it only with the numbers that start with an x

```
awk '{ print $3 + $4 + $4}'
```

Input:

col1 col2 2344 4324 3544 col6 col7
col1 col2  **x200   x300   x400**  col6 col7
col1 col2 3543 5442 9403 col6 col7

Result:

col1 col2 2344 4324 3544 col6 col7
col1 col2  **900**  col6 col7
col1 col2 3543 5442 9403 col6 col7

Comment: Could you please check answer once and let us know if that helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
$3~/^x/ && $4~/^x/ && $5~/^x/{
  sub(/^x/,"",$3)
  sub(/^x/,"",$4)
  sub(/^x/,"",$5)
  $3=$3+$4+$5
  $4=$5=""
}
1
'  Input_file | column -t
```

Have kept `column` command at last to get output in TAB delimited you could remove it in case you want output in simple spaces format.